# [Flutter Error]-Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, build

I recently formatted my pc and upgraded to windows 11.When I try to run my flutter app on my mobile phone,I get this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Failed to create parent directory 'C:\Users\HP' when creating directory
'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\OWASLO\care_receiver_app\ss_carereceiver_app\android\app\build\intermed iates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets'

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option 
 to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 56s
 Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

the path mentioned in the error log

> C:\Users\HP\Desktop\OWASLO\care_receiver_app\ss_carereceiver_app\android\app\build\intermed
> iates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets

is where my app was before I formatted and

> "C:\Users\HP"

was the user name before the laptop was formatted.
The app works fine on chrome but wont work on mobile.
Please help!!!